# display a file in UIWebView from local disk using XCode.

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have downloaded a PDF file form a web url and saved it on disk. I want to view the same file in webView. i used:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.fileViewController animated:YES];
```

i am using this code to navigate to other view controller. Following is my code in viewDidLoad:

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

}
```

Just tell me that where  i am wrong. thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Where you added webView ?

Comment: i am just running the code i posted earlier. i am creating it in my initNib method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will help you...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"pdf"];
        NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
    }
```

Comment: i am sorry but can you tell me that what is the difference in this one and mine?

Comment: You didn't added this line in your code... [self.view addSubview:webView];

Answer (score 2):

I have checked your code and it works. May be you need to add webview as subview to your view controller by using following code:     `[self.view addSubview:webView];`